# Problem with SLD/OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl

I've started to do sth. with SDL/openGL, but I haven't managed to get this tutorial running yet (http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics).

Since this tutorial, or most tutorials at all, are  written in SDL 1.2, I  changed just this part of the tutorial's code:

instead of:

```
if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_OPENGL)) == NULL)
```

to:

```
SDL_Window *window;
if((window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLWindow", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              640, 480,
                              SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)) == NULL)
```

Now, all parts of the code seem to be correctly except the last one, this is "SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()";

Xcode says: use of undeclared identifier....

I think it's deprecated in SDL 2.0, but I couldn't find the right function in the migration guide, or is the problem something else?

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

The new function is `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()` and it takes your window pointer.

Comment: I already tried SDL_GL_SwapWindow(pointer), but it does exactly the same like without this function: instead of a sdl window with  that simple graphic, i got an enlarged view on a part of the XCode GUI(like 300 %), no keyboard input is possible and so i have restart my mac completely by pushing the on/off button...

Comment: Have you acquired an OpenGL context yet using `SDL_GL_CreateContext(window)`?

Comment: No I did not...Actually i was under the impression, SDL_createWindow() provides this functionality and in this tutorial, there is no usage of SDL_GL_CreateContext(window) . However I have tried so, if i put this function before SDL_GL_CreateContext(window), there is no difference in behavior, if i put it after, i get the enlarged view of Xcode but after a second, it moves away and I  get a full black screen. Really weird and frustrating.......

Comment: >> "i got an enlarged view on a part of the XCode GUI(like 300 %)" <<

 That's good! It is probably your OpenGL backing buffer, but you haven't drawn anything into it. (It has a different app's contents still sitting in it.) I think you're ready to do glClearColor() and glClear(). Do a clear, a swap, a clear, and a swap, all at once if you like, just to check that theory.

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with developing on OSX so I wasn't sure if that was a problem.  In SDL you need to explicitly tell the application to handle input events so that your window is responsive.  You can do this with a call to `SDL_QuitRequested()`, `SDL_PumpEvents()` or with `SDL_PollEvent()` in a loop.

Comment: I have loop, calling the SDL_PollEvent..Obviously neither that was the problem, nor david van brink's theory...Now I'm a bit more far with my problem. I get the result that i want as shown at this tutorial, as long i leave the SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER Flag out, if I use it, i get the problem, described earlier.....hmmm